# Query for a specific label on an image?

Tags: computer-vision, google-cloud-vision, amazon-rekognition

is there a computer vision api (not necessarily google) where I can specify which label I want to query for on an image?

everything I've looked at so far (aws, azure & gcs) all only give a method that returns a set of labels chosen by the service but I want to send an image with eg the label "dog" and ensure that I will get a response that gives me a rating on that image for "dog".

Comment: You don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

The **Vision API Labels** feature supports the detection of broad sets of categories within an image; however, it is not currently possible to set the specific the label that you want to validate. Based on this, a possible workaround could be to perform the Vision API request and go through the response content in order to determine if the label that you are querying has been found based on the image sent to the service.

In case this feature doesn't cover your current needs, you can use the **Send Feedback** button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [service public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels), as well as take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in order to [raise a Vision API feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1010433) and notify to Google about this desired functionality.